# Exporting Folder Structure & Subdirectories/files to text

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line

I am trying to export the folder structure and it's files of my portable hard drive to a text file to have offsite access.

I want to be able to copy the folder structure of my Music folder (100 GB+) to a text file including the files within the nested folders.

Note: I only want to copy the structure and layout of the folder and it's subdirectories and files, not the actual file.

I did some searching and found the following command used in PowerShell to acheive an output like I desire but it doesn't give me the filelist inside subfolders.

The command was:

```
Get-ChildItem | tree > Music_Structure.txt
```

I would like something similar to the following output in the text file.

```
C:.
├───Music
│   ├───Eminem
│   │   └───The Eminem Show
│   │       └───01 Curtains Up (skit).flac
                02 White America.flac
```

and so on.

I have tried other options such as Command Prompt `tree` command and `dir` command but doesn't give me a clean output.

Looking for a certain command or method that I can do every other month to maintain that text file.

Operating System: Windows 10 x64 Version 1809

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use `tree /F` and then it will include the files in the folders. You also don't need to use `Get-ChildItem` at all, you can just provide a path to tree:

```
tree /f c:\your\music\folder > Music_Structure.txt
```

Note also that `tree` is not a PowerShell command but rather a command line executable, so you can use it directly in a command prompt.

```
~> tree /? 

Graphically displays the folder structure of a drive or path.

TREE [drive:][path] [/F] [/A]

   /F   Display the names of the files in each folder.
   /A   Use ASCII instead of extended characters.
```